# Python code with multiprocessing does not work on Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, multiprocessing

The following naive, absolute-beginner code works 100% well on Ubuntu 14.04 (Python 2.7.6) and Cygwin (Python 2.7.8) but it hangs on Windows 64-bit (Python 2.7.8).  I have observed the same with another snippets using the **multiprocessing** package.

```html
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import time

def WallisPi(N,out):    # Pi by the (slowly convergent) Wallis method.
    prod = 1.0
    for i in xrange(2,N,2):
        prod = prod*(i**2)/((i+1)**2)
    prod = 2.0e0*prod*(i+1)
    out.put(prod)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    T = [15000000, 25000000, 30000000, 40000000]
    
    ti = time()
    
    q1 = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=WallisPi, args=(T[0],q1))
    p1.start()
    
    q2 = Queue()
    p2 = Process(target=WallisPi, args=(T[1],q2))
    p2.start()

    q3 = Queue()
    p3 = Process(target=WallisPi, args=(T[2],q3))
    p3.start()

    q4 = Queue()
    p4 = Process(target=WallisPi, args=(T[3],q4))
    p4.start()
    
    p = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
    
    for item in p:
        item.join()

    q = [q1, q2, q3, q4]
    
    print "\n"
    
    Num = len(q)
    
    for i in range(0,Num):
        print "Pi at ",T[i], "terms = ", q[i].get()

    tf = time()
    print "\nElapsed time: ", round((tf-ti),2), " secs."
```

I wonder what's wrong with this code?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Fausto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you run Python, you might need to use [`freeze_support`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) on Windows:

> One needs to call this function straight after the `if __name__ == '__main__'` line of the main module. For example:
>
> ```
> from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
>
> def f():
>     print 'hello world!'
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     freeze_support()
>     Process(target=f).start()
> ```

See also the [programming guidelines on Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

Comment: Hi Ferdinand, thanks!

In fact, I found out that the code eventually runs on Windows without the freeze_support() call provided I give it time enough (an obscene amount of time, may I say) to finish.  It wasn't hanging; it just takes 14 times longer to execute on Windows than it does on Cygwin.  The problem isn't Windows; it is I who am impatient.  ;-)

Thanks,